# How do saiyans get the evil saiyan form?

Tags: dragon-ball-heroes

Cumber and Turles in Dragon Ball Heroes are able to get an "evil saiyan" form with a red aura.

[image]

[image]

What do saiyans have to do to get this form?

Answer (score 1):

The Evil Super Saiyan form is a level of Super Saiyan is a form used by Saiyans who's hearts have been tainted by darkness. Any Saiyan to achieve this form immediantly gains access to its other five levels. The first known Saiyan to achieve this form of Super Saiyan was Turles
The form increases a Saiyan's power by five times as much as the regular Super Saiyan form would. This goes for the other levels of Evil Super Saiyan as well. (For example, if one were to use Evil Super Saiyan 2, it would increase the user's power by fives times that of a regular Super Saiyan 2.)
Credits : https://ultradragonball.fandom.com/wiki/Evil_Super_Saiyan